# What's "asynchronous multi-threaded search" in the AlphaGo Paper?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, asynchronous

In the AlphaGo Paper ([here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v529/n7587/full/nature16961.html) or [here](https://gogameguru.com/i/2016/03/deepmind-mastering-go.pdf)), it says that

> Evaluating policy and value networks requires several orders of
>   magnitude more computation than traditional search heuristics. To
>   efficiently combine MCTS with deep neural networks, AlphaGo uses an
>   **asynchronous multi-threaded search** that executes simulations on CPUs,
>   and computes policy and value networks in parallel on GPUs. The final
>   version of AlphaGo used 40 search threads, 48 CPUs, and 8 GPUs. We
>   also implemented a distributed version of AlphaGo that exploited
>   multiple machines, 40 search threads, 1,202 CPUs and 176 GPUs. The
>   Methods section provides full details of asynchronous and distributed
>   MCTS.

I know *asynchronous* in several ways: the callback style of Node.js, the asynchronous I/O, etc... But what does *asynchronous multi-threaded search* exactly mean? I think it must have something to do with exploit CPUs when waiting GPUs to return results.